# 1970s Television horror show where a suit of armour comes to life and carries off a young boy

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I remember only this scene from what I believe was a horror themed TV show from the '70s.
I was born in 1970, so I think I watched it between 1973 and 1977? It was in color and it was seen on U.S. television and appeared to be shot on videotape, which is why I say it was a TV show or TV movie. It could have been British also because there was no dialogue in the scene.

In the scene, a medieval suit of armor is standing in a hallway like you see in castles in horror movies. It seems to come to life and comes walking down the hall and into the room of a sleeping boy, who looked to be about 8? years old and with brown hair, and then carries him back out of the room and down the hallway. This was a very scary scene and had a real horror vibe to it and it was at this time a grown-up said something like 'you shouldn't be watching this' or something like that and turned it off!

I also don't think it was "Dark Shadows", but I could be wrong. I seem to remember it was at night when I saw this. I know the British produced lots of television horror that was shot on videotape at this time.

It was definitely shot on videotape and had the look of a "Dark Shadows" or "Doctor Who" episode.

Comment: Probably not "Rent a Ghost". That was a G-rated kid's afternoon show. Not horror at all.

Comment: Right, and I think I saw it in the evening, but it had the same shot-on-video look.

Comment: I wonder if it could be Sapphire and Steel ? I seem to remember a scene with civil war suit of armour in one episode. That was a fairly spooky show.

Comment: @Sarriesfan, this looks promising. From skimming through that episode, I don't think it's the one but it looks like a great show. I can't believe I've never even heard of this one! I see that it all seems to be available on Youtube, so I'm going to start watching them and I will see if this is it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is faintly reminiscent of an episode of The Night Stalker I saw once but a quick look online shows it is quite hard to find much more info about individual episodes

Comment: @Danny3414. Thanks, but that's not it, I have the entire series on DVD and I've seen that one. This one was shot on video tape. I think it might be an episode of ABC Wide World of Mystery, but some of those don't even have plot descriptions on IMDb. I don't think I will find this.

Comment: Mentioning "Wide World of Mystery" is good.  I was thinking it might not be a purely horror-based production, but you caught the particularly spooky scene.  It could easily be a re-run of "The Avengers", which often had villain shenanigans faking up supernatural threats.  "Doctor Who" comes to mind.  Even "The Saint" had a plot or three that could qualify as "horror".

Comment: Sapphire and steel is also available on Tubi a free app for phone and computer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was Kolchak: The Night Stalker the episode called The Knightly Murders

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches?

Comment: This was my first thought also, as I remember there was a Suit of Armor episode. But although I watched the series over again 10-15 years ago, I dont recall the specifics of the episode.

Comment: Ok Just watched the episode online and it does NOT match the OPs description. The Suit does kill 2 people in their beds, but there are no children in the episode, Nor does the suit kidnap anyone and carry them away.

Comment: @Brockenstein. Someone already suggested the Night Stalker episode, but it's not the one. I have the series on DVD and I've seen every episode, but thanks for trying.